# how to obtain access to the (child) controls in webusercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net

i had created an web user control whish i insert an form of registration (textbox,label...)

and i have create an page of registration wish it will include the web user control

and i want to get access of those textbox,label in the page ho it will include the webusercotrol

i want to access this controls in page load of the container of page webusercontrol

what can i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, Create property for each control in UserControl and access them in web page

```
public string TextboxValue
{
    get { return txtMyText.Text; }
    set { txtMyText.Text= value; }
}
```